# Passing 'argument lists' as a namedtuple in python

Tags: python, import, namedtuple

I created a namedtuple called Engine that holds most of the information I want to pass around my program.  Inside of this tuple, are a couple of parameters and two instanced classes that are used by methods downstream.

```
Engine = namedtuple('Engine', 'website, browser, s, e')
engine = Engine(website, browser, s(), e())
```

i have a function, `download(engine)` that I pass `engine` into.  Subfunctions in `download` pass `engine`-- some of them use `website`, some of them use `browser`, some of them use `s`, and some use `e`.

Now, the cognitive overhead (of me as a programmer) goes down considerably, I no longer have to ensure that argument lists are up to date both downstream and upstream of a particular change that might happen-- I just pass `engine` downstream, and if I use an argument in a method, i use `engine.foo`.

On the other, it feels like this is 'lazy' programming-- just wrapping everything up into an engine 'class' and having the variables as methods on the class seems to make everything almost too easy.  Further, I'd swear that there was some kind of overhead I'm not seeing with this implementation.  Is there any kind of precedent to this, cause it feels too useful to ignore.

Should I be using namedtuples as replacement for arguments throughout my program to reduce the number of arguments that get passed?

Comment: What exactly is the question? _How_ to pass namedtuples as argument lists, or if you should?

Comment: Whether I should. /edit for clarity.

Comment: If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Comment: First, if there is a conceptual object that fits into your object model—and it certainly sounds like Engine is such a thing—then you should definitely pass it around. But probably as a class, not a namedtuple. If not, the question is whether you're using a http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject or abusing a http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicContainer, and it's hard to guess without looking at the details of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say this is actually a very good pattern. `namedtuples` are extremely efficient and increase readability a lot. Their space overhead compared to regular tuples is effectively zero.

So `namedtuples` could be seen as kind of lightweight classes, and can be grown into them if their responsibilities increase.

Raymond Hettinger explains their advantages and use cases in quite some detail in this [Talk from PyCon US 2011](http://pyvideo.org/video/367/pycon-2011--fun-with-python--39-s-newer-tools) `[11:35 - 26:00]`, much better than I ever could.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like some variant of a [parameter object pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject). On the other hand, it sounds like you could implement it as a class as well, i.e.

```
class Engine(object):
   website = ...
   browser = ...
   s = ...
   e = ...

   def download(self):
       ...
   def _sub_function(self):
       ...
```

Comment: +1. I struggled for 5 minutes to fit all this into a comment, and meanwhile you wrote it up 10x more clearly…

Comment: Yeah, from what I understand, as `namedtuple` gets more complex, you can simply `class EngineClass(Engine)` and it should work with all defined methods.

Comment: @kreativitea You can even put properties on namedtuples, to act as simple methods (that take no arguments) and of course subclass them as you said.